# Middy onError not called

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, middy

I'm using lambda powertools and middy for cross-cutting concerns. I have a simple error middleware

```
export const errorLogger = ({ logger }: { logger: Logger }): middy.MiddlewareObj => {
  const onError = async (request: middy.Request) => {
    console.log("ERROR LOGGER MIDDLEWARE CALLED");
    const error = request.error === null ? new Error("An unknown error occured.") : request.error;
    logger.error(`Error occured: ${error.message}`, error);
  };

  return { onError };
};
```

The logger above comes from lambda powertools and is a JSON logger. However when the lambda throws an error, this middleware is never called / used. Not even the console.log shows up on CloudFront.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the provided error logger, `@middy/error-logger` (https://middy.js.org/docs/middlewares/error-logger), or use it as a starting point for your own custom one (https://github.com/middyjs/middy/blob/main/packages/error-logger/index.js).